# weird undefined variable python3

Tags: python, load, python-3.4, nameerror

I'm trying to dynamically load a python file and to retrieve its variables.

Here is my code :

```
test_files = glob.glob("./test/*.py")
for test_file in test_files:
    exec(open(test_file).read())
    print(dir())
    print(test_list)
```

`test_file` is the shared variable I want to retrieve.

`print(dir())` displays: `['test_file', 'test_files', 'test_list']`
so `test_list` exists.

The line after:

`print(test_list)` display the traceback:

```
NameError: name 'test_list' is not defined
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Is this in a function?

Comment: yes, here is all my code : http://pastie.org/9983986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `exec()` (or `eval()`) to set local variables; the local namespace is highly optimised.

What you are looking at is the `locals()` dictionary, a one-way reflection of the local namespace; the name was added to that dictionary, but not to the real namespace.

Use a dedicated namespace instead:

```
namespace = {}
exec(open(test_file).read(), namespace)
print(namespace['test_list'])
```